# REST API Route Structure

Tags: api, node.js, rest

Having some trouble deciding which route is more RESTful. To give a quick rundown, I'm building an API for a sweepstakes application. The highest level is client, next is sweepstakes, and following is a submission.

I'm confused on what route would be best for creating a new sweepstakes, and submission.

**Option 1**

```
POST /sweepstakes [passing along client_id as a parameter]
```

**Option 2**

```
POST /clients/:client_id/sweepstakes [using client id in route to create]
```

Here is a GIST of all my routes. Hopefully someone can help me out. https://gist.github.com/4504221

Comment: I am going to blather on for a while if you don't mind. A primary part of REST (some might say the most important part) is the separation of the identification of a resource and its transformations. This means that the URI should stay the same no matter what you are doing (retrieving, creating, updating, deleting or any other action.) The general type of action should be represented by the HTTP verb (get, post, put delete, etc.) and the specifics should be passed in the request body (form post data.)

Comment: First you ask which route style is more RESTful. Then you ask which route style would be best. Realize that these are not necessarily the same thing. Also, what is considered "RESTful" can be getting into a pretty touchy, subjective subject.

Comment: I don't think the insinuation that @mark-hildreth made that REST is some touchy political or subjective opinion is true, constructive or helpful in any way. REST is a philosophy developed to build better network application architectures. Therefore being more RESTful is often what is better.

Comment: @protonfish: My insinuation is that the term "RESTful" is so often used to mean varying things that it doesn't really have well-understood definition, and therefore is probably better off not being used as the primary point of a question. The question could be better worded by giving a better definition than to say they want what is "more RESTful" or "best".

Comment: @mark-hildreth: Just because some people misunderstand REST and use the term incorrectly does not mean it lacks a well-understood definition. [Chapter 5 of Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is quite clear about what REST is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not bother making the REST URIs represent the hierarchical structure.

```
/client/:client_id should return a list of the client's sweepstakes URIs (among other data.)
/sweepstakes/:sweepstakes_id will return a list of all submissions URIs for that sweepstakes id (among other data.)
/submission/:submission_id is exactly what you think.
```

This is simple, but I can't think of a reason to make the URIs more complex. Let me know if I am missing something.

Edit: Oh you were referring to creating a resource:

I'd still go with the above URIs.

```
POST /client/
POST /sweepstakes/
POST /submission/
```

Pass the data needed in the request body and return the id in the response. Update with PUT:

```
PUT /client/:client_id
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is nearly related to what will be the URI of the resource you will create:

- `POST /` to create `/:id`
- `POST /sweepstakes/` to create `/sweepstakes/:id`
- `POST /clients/:id_a/sweepstakes/` to create `/clients/:id_a/sweepstakes/:id_b`